# Can a Good Listener Help Me Translate?

Tags: translation, word-choice, characters, simplified-characters, character-identification

I am translating a paragraph from English into Chinese, going by a recording a native speaker made. I am trying to use the same characters that they are using in their spoken translation, but am having difficulty with one passage. The passage's English source material is the following:

"A major goal of language learning is to acquire the ability to communicate in that language."

I've attached a link to the speaker's recording. The passage above begins at about 54 seconds in, with the passage I'm having trouble with beginning at about 57 seconds (at "就是...") and ends at about 1:05 (at "为了..."

https://vocaroo.com/i/s1egf4TlxINm

I can't seem to find the exact characters the speaker uses. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

就是掌握用那种语言去交流的能力

The speaker's pronunciation is not perfect. The pronunciation of "那" (the intended pronunciation should be nei4 here) is not good.

那 is often pronounced as nei4 in speech.

Answer (score 2):

**(0:54)   语言学习的一个主要目的** - One of the primary goal of language leaning

**(0:57)   就是掌握用另一种语言去交流的能力** - is to obtain the ability to communicate with another language

**(1:04)   为了这个目的** - To that end

**(1:07)   你已经学会了如何对一些基本的社交场合作出反应** - You’ve already learnt how to react to some basic social occasions

*Due to the accent and inexperience of the speaker, on 0:57, she read the "另一种" part way too fast. It's normal for native speaker to speak that way, but will definitely cause misunderstandings for foreigners.*